# Affinity of a process in a multicore system Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: virtualization, cpu, process

We have multiple processes running on a multicore (8 cores) VM.
Most of them are Java. On another box which is not a V, they run fine. But on this one everything seems sluggish at times.

top shows 99% CPU usage but IT says that is not a problem as its 8 core.

Anyway to know if all 8 or only few cores are available to the java processes (due to some mis-configuration in the VMs)?

Is there a way to know if the Java processes are being affected by the scanner that is hogging 50% of 2 cores? In windows an see it in the task manager https://ibb.co/mNJhqF 
[image: Windows Task affinity to CPUs/cores. Image from https://www.mt4copier.com/improve-mt4-trade-copier-speed/]
our server is non GUI, so need terminal command(s)

Any command/ steps to know how much of CPU time the Java processes want vs what they are getting?

Following is output of top (after typing 1 to see per core usage. Removed extra spaces so can format well in spreadsheet replace "  " with " "  and "\n " with " " )

```
top - 15:05:33 up 56 days, 13:35, 7 users, load average: 1.06, 1.08, 1.06
Tasks: 482 total, 2 running, 480 sleeping, 0 stopped, 0 zombie
%Cpu0 : 0.3 us, 0.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.3 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu1 : 0.3 us, 0.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.0 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu2 : 0.0 us, 0.0 sy, 0.0 ni,100.0 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu3 : 99.0 us, 0.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 0.0 id, 0.3 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu4 : 0.3 us, 1.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 98.7 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu5 : 0.3 us, 0.0 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.7 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu6 : 0.3 us, 0.3 sy, 0.0 ni, 99.3 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
%Cpu7 : 0.7 us, 0.7 sy, 0.0 ni, 98.7 id, 0.0 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
KiB Mem: 32934880 total, 32335788 used, 599092 free, 942292 buffers
KiB Swap: 9202684 total, 1338100 used, 7864584 free. 10891396 cached Mem

PID    USER   PR NI VIRT     RES      SHR   S    %CPU %MEM TIME+     COMMAND 
14445  AVuser 20 0  376708   143972   3772  R    99.4 0.4  5:10.55   scanner 
11045  user1  20 0  7162456  662720   11024 S    0.7  2.0  11:27.62  java    
15685  root3  20 0  25.125g  585900   5300  S    0.7  1.8  156:19.28 java    
123326 root3  20 0  5598660  218820   9792  S    0.7  0.7  15:43.57  java    
12942  user1  20 0  5366300  409164   5984  S    0.3  1.2  203:47.47 java    
14685  user1  20 0  34856    2088     1236  R    0.3  0.0  0:00.08   top     
46018  user1  20 0  6417468  464356   15336 S    0.3  1.4  3:46.92   java    
46645  user1  20 0  11.936g  2.837g   15020 S    0.3  9.0  3:53.25   java    
47504  user1  20 0  3654616  41888    12124 S    0.3  0.1  1:52.82   java    
47528  user1  20 0  5683220  316128   15408 S    0.3  1.0  2:51.20   java    
122516 root3  20 0  12.371g  176716   9160  S    0.3  0.5  3:36.29   java    
122701 root3  20 0  12.374g  177420   9216  S    0.3  0.5  4:00.00   java    
122848 root3  20 0  12.373g  172008   9176  S    0.3  0.5  3:43.66   java    
129623 user1  20 0  3654624  48728    10472 S    0.3  0.1  3:03.76   java    
129653 user1  20 0  6650800  401032   12188 S    0.3  1.2  7:30.19   java    
130620 root3  20 0  3645888  44848    6696  S    0.3  0.1  15:05.26  java
```

Updates:
There are 8 VMs on on one physical system. 
Drives are on the same physical system.

1 VM has the java processes  that talk to mysql and write logs (log4j latest, with async) hardened; 
3 of the java processes do write small text files in their outbox, ut they are working okay - deleting after processing in a few seconds

1 VM is for mysql (open source) sligthly more hardened. 
All are ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I/O - should be minimal. How can I test this? Is there any utility i can write on my local dev system and then on the VM?

Comment: That looks like the bottleneck is I/O and not CPU time. What are the java processes doing? Are they reading data from disk? How does the VM access that disk?

Comment: @terdon there are 8 VMs on on one physical system. Drives are on the same system. 1 VM has the java processed that talk to mysql and write logs (log4j latest, with async) hardened; 1 VM is for mysql (open source) sligthly more hardened. All are ubuntu  14.04 LTS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add extra information. Comments are easy to miss, hard to read and can be deleted without warning. That said, when you edit, please explain how the drives are accessed. "On the same system" isn't very informative when talking about VMs. If the drives are physically present on the host, tell us that and explain how they are being shared with the VM. Again, though, the main issue here is that CPU is obviously not the bottleneck since your java processes use very little CPU. That is often a sign that I/O is happening and that is what is slowing you down.

Comment: @terdon added more details.

Comment: hi @terdon i will look at the IO seperately. same apps work fine when put directly on boxes. Anyway to know if all 8 or only few cores are available to the java processes (due to some mis-configuration in the VMs)? Thank you

Comment: The simplest test would be to run one of the processes by itself and see if it still takes a small amount of CPU. However, I can't imagine how it would be possible for your process *not* to have access to all CPUs.  The fact that each is only using less than 1% strongly suggests your bottleneck is elsewhere.

Comment: Well its one API gateway that depends on other micro services. i will try what ur saying. i was hoping for some command / view like in windows process manager where u can see  a process and view (and edit) which CPUs are serving it.

Comment: like this https://ibb.co/mNJhqF put in question too

Comment: What's the point of that? In Linux, the kernel manages this automatically and there is no reason to think that some of your processes don't have access to a CPU. Even if that were possible, you would be seeing CPU% of ~100 since the percentages shown are per CPU.